# Data structures for iterating through multiple collections

Tags: c++, for-loop, templates, iterator

I have objects that have timestamps, lets say:

```
class data_point
{
     public:
     data_point(time_t _ts, char _data):timestamp(_ts), data(_data) {}
     time_t timestamp;
     char    data;
}
```

And lets say that you have N collections of these data points. For each collection, you know they are in chronological sequence. What I want to do, is iterate through these collections, such that I will get a callback once for each data_point, but in the correct order. Basically I'm looking for a data structure that can be initialized with N collections, and return an iterator which will allow going through them picking the next item with the "lowest" timestamp, giving precedence to the collections added to the set first. Ideally the code could look like this:

```
std::vector<data_point> a1 = { data_point(1, 'a'), data_point(6, 'b'), data_point(11, 'c') };
std::vector<data_point> a2 = { data_point(1, 'd'), data_point(8, 'e'), data_point(12, 'f') };
std::vector<data_point> a3 = { data_point(1, 'g'), data_point(9, 'h'), data_point(11, 'i') };

SomeCollection c = { a1, a2, a3 }; 
// or possibly if needed
// SomeCollection c; c.add(a1); c.add(a2); c.add(a3);
for(auto &d: c)
{
     std::cout << d.data << std::endl;
}
```

Which would output:

```
a
d
g
b
e
h
c
i
f
```

I could write my own class, but wondering if there is already something like this that exists.

Comment: Is the intent to leave the N collections unchanged?   Or are you just looking to access their values in sequence for (say) printing?

Comment: Yes, keep initial collections, but have an iterator which treats them like queues, where ++ moves you to the next item across all collections with the lowest queue.

Comment: Are the inputs guaranteed in order?

Comment: @Caleth - Yes, assume each collection, in this case a vector, is already in order. Ideally this would work with other collections as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a collection of collections i.e. `std::vector<std::vector<data_point>> dataPointCollectors`;

Add data into these and then iterate and print things

Comment: This doesnt give me an iterator which works as described in original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly insert and `std::inplace_merge` from each input.

```
std::vector<data_point> c;

for (auto * a : { &a1, &a2, &a3 })
{
    auto mid = c.size();
    c.insert(c.end(), a->begin(), a->end());
    std::inplace_merge(c.begin(), c.begin() + mid, c.end());
}
```

Comment: This appears to concatenate the collections. I want to treat them all like queues, but have an iterator which moves to the next item across all collections with the lowest timestamp.